# How To Send sms in Multiple Languages

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I wonder how countries like Canada or India and other countries send SMS to subscribers in multiple languages?

When using data extension for use we need 5 characters locales (ex., en_us, fr_ca).

So I wonder how to use different locales for sending SMS

I am looking for actual examples of sending SMS to people using different languages.